# How to properly index and query time series data in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm experimenting with Postgres recently instead of using Bigquery.

My table `transactions_all` structure

```
access_id (text)
serial_no (text)
transaction_id (text)
date_local (timestamp)
```

and an `index (BTREE, condition (((date_local)::date), serial_no))`

When I'm loading 500.000 rows for one month into this table, performance is okay to query the last 2 days like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM transactions_all 
WHERE DATE(date_local) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day'  AND CURRENT_DATE 
 AND access_id = 'accessid1' 
 and serial_no = 'IO99267637'
```

But if I'm selecting the last 21 days like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM transactions_all 
WHERE DATE(date_local) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '20 day'  AND CURRENT_DATE 
  AND access_id = 'accessid1' 
  and serial_no = 'IO99267637'
```

then fetching the data takes multiple seconds instead of milliseconds.

Is this a normal behaviour or am I using the wrong index?

Comment: How many rows will you get when you use the last 21 days' query.

Comment: Could you provide your execute plan for your second query?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) for the slow query generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Try `date_local::date` (the expression used in the index) instead of `DATE(date_local)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your index columns are in the wrong order. In the front you need those expressions that are used with the `=` operator in the `WHERE` condition, because index columns after the column that is used with a different operator can no longer be used.

To understand that, imagine a phone book where the names are ordered by (last name, first name). Then consider that it is easy to find all entries with last name "Miller" and a first name less than "J": you just read the "Miller" entries until you hit "J". Now consider that the task is to find all "Joe"s whole last name is less than "M": you have to scan all entries up to "M", and it doesn't help you much that the first names are sorted too.

So use an index like

```
CREATE INDEX ON transactions_all (serial_no, access_id, date(date_local));
```

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation! It put this index onto my table and it increased the performance dramatically.